# SetVisible is not showing up a second JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, visible

I've created a JFrame that when performs a button action calls a second JFrame that is instantiated in the constructor of the first JFrame and only setVisible(true) in this performed action but is not showing up, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so... here I hit a small part of my code:

Main JFrame

```
public Main() {
    initComponents();
    Datos datos = new Datos();
}

private void jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        datos.setVisible(true);
}
```

Second Frame

```
public class Datos extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form Datos
 */
public Datos() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextUser = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextPass = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextURL = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButtonOK = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButtonCancelar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jTextUser.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextPass.setText("jTextField2");

    jLabel1.setText("Usuario:");

    jLabel2.setText("Contraseña:");

    jTextURL.setText("jTextField1");
    jTextURL.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextURLActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setText("URL del repositorio:");

    jButtonOK.setText("OK");

    jButtonCancelar.setText("Cancelar");

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(80, 80, 80)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(jLabel3)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                    .add(jTextURL)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(jLabel2)
                            .add(jLabel1))
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                            .add(jTextUser)
                            .add(jTextPass, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
            .addContainerGap(92, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jButtonOK)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(jButtonCancelar)
            .add(28, 28, 28))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(67, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(jTextURL, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(jTextUser, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(jLabel1))
            .add(18, 18, 18)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(jTextPass, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(jLabel2))
            .add(51, 51, 51)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(jButtonOK)
                .add(jButtonCancelar))
            .add(23, 23, 23))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextURLActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonCancelar;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonOK;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextPass;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextURL;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextUser;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: So... How I show it up?

Comment: I meant of course that *Datos* is actually a `JPanel` and **not** a `JFrame` as you describe. To display a `JPanel` you need to add it to a top level container such as `JFrame` or a `JDialog`. Also take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/1048330)

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)